# Modifying document.body.offsetWidth as soon as document.body becomes available

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

My goal is to re-initialize certain Javascript read-only variables such as document.body.offsetWidth for the entire page, including iframes in it:

```
Object.defineProperty(document.body, 'offsetWidth', {
   value: 1000, /*OVERRIDING VALUE*/
   writable: false,
   configurable: true
});
```

For this, I used page.evaluateOnNewDocument() and ran the above code inside a Javascript file attached to this function. But I get the following error:

```
VM14:73 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
at Function.defineProperty ()
at :73:8
```

I think by the time page.evaluateOnNewDocument() is called for each new .html, the  tag has not been parsed, is not available yet, and thus the error occurs. Could there be a solution for this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worth a try:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      for (const mutation of mutations) {
        if (Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).some(node => node.nodeName === 'BODY')) {
          observer.disconnect();
          Object.defineProperty(document.body, 'offsetWidth', {
             value: 1000,
             writable: false,
             configurable: true
          });
        }
      }
    })
    observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
  });

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.body.offsetWidth;
  });
  console.log(data);
} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```